# Configuring Roundcube password plugin with Postfix/Dovecot

Tags: postfix, email-server, dovecot, roundcube

I am using Roundcube v**1.6.0**, and I am trying to get the **Password Plugin** to work properly.

However, I am getting the following error message (in browser):

```
Could not save new password.
Encryption function missing.
```

Why does Roundcube want to access my private key?

I am using Postfix/Dovecot configured for virtual users with Postfixadmin.

---

### Configuration

`/srv/live/php/roundcubemail-1.6.0/logs/errors.log`

```
[13-Dec-2022 11:16:31 -0500]: PHP Error: Password plugin: Failed to execute command: /usr/bin/doveadm pw -s 'CRAM-MD5'.  
Error: doveconf: Fatal: Error in configuration file /etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf line 12: ssl_cert: Can't open file /etc/ssl/private/fullchain.pem: Permission denied in /srv/live/php/roundcubemail-1.6.0/plugins/password/password.php on line 747 (POST /?_task=settings&_action=plugin.password-save)
```

**edit**: *I mistakenly listed the below as the Roundcube main config file; this is the password plugin config*

`/srv/live/php/roundcubemail-1.6.0/plugins/password`

```
$config['password_driver'] = 'sql';
$config['password_strength_driver'] = 'zxcvbn';
$config['password_zxcvbn_min_score'] = 5;
$config['password_confirm_current'] = true;
$config['password_minimum_length'] = 8;
$config['password_minimum_score'] = 0;
$config['password_algorithm'] = 'dovecot';
$config['password_algorithm_options'] = [];
$config['password_algorithm_prefix'] = '';
$config['password_dovecotpw'] = '/usr/bin/doveadm pw';
$config['password_dovecotpw_method'] = 'CRAM-MD5';
$config['password_dovecotpw_with_method'] = true;
```

`/etc/dovecot/dovecot-sql.conf`

```
driver = mysql
connect = host=localhost dbname=postfix_db user=postfix password=<redacted>
default_pass_scheme = MD5-CRYPT
user_query = SELECT '/var/www/mail/vmail/%d/%n' as home, 'maildir:/var/www/mail/vmail/%d/%n' as mail, 2000 AS uid, 2000 AS gid, concat('dirsize:storage=',  quota) AS quota FROM mailbox WHERE username = '%u' AND active = '1'
# Get the password
password_query = SELECT username as user, password, '/var/www/mail/vmail/%d/%n' as userdb_home, 'maildir:/var/www/mail/vmail/%d/%n' as userdb_mail, 2000 as userdb_uid, 2000 as userdb_gid FROM mailbox WHERE username = '%u' AND active = '1'
# If using client certificates for authentication, comment the above and uncomment the following
#password_query = SELECT null AS password, ‘%u’ AS user
```

Thank you so much in advance for your help!

---

sidenote: I was unable to find any posts detailing my exact problem.

I did find two posters with rather similar setups/errors that were solved by changing Dovecot's password schema from **MD5** to **bcrypt**.  I am not sure why that might help; but since I was planning to do this anyway please let me know if this is somehow the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a long journey, but I fixed it.  Ended up going to the [Postfixadmin git](https://github.com/postfixadmin) and finding [this issue](https://github.com/postfixadmin/postfixadmin/issues/398) with [this post](https://github.com/postfixadmin/postfixadmin/issues/398#issuecomment-843124406).  The subsequent error `Error: net_connect_unix(/run/dovecot/stats-writer) failed: Permission denied` was solved thanks to [this post](https://forums.freebsd.org/threads/mail-dovecot-stats-writer-failed-permission-denied.69723/)

To summarize:

#### 1.  Make new dovecot config file

You will first make a new file in `/etc/dovecot/` (or wherever your dovecot config files lives).
I call mine `ssl-keys.conf`.  The permissions for this file are `0600` (owner is `root:root`)

This will contain only two (2) lines that are moved from your primary dovecot config file (presumably `dovecot.conf`):

**`ssl-keys.conf`**

```
ssl_cert                   = </etc/ssl/private/fullchain.pem
ssl_key                    = </etc/ssl/private/privkey.pem
```

#### 2.  Modify the main dovecot config file

In `dovecot.conf`, add the following lines

```
!include_try ssl-keys.conf

service stats {
    unix_listener stats-reader {
        group = vmail
        mode = 0666
    }

    unix_listener stats-writer {
        group = vmail
        mode = 0666
    }
}
```

Make sure postfixadmin is part of the dovecot/vmail group (where vmail is your mail or virtual user group).

If you have not done so already, remove the lines from `dovecot.conf` that you added to new file `ssl-keys.conf`.  Leave everything else as is.

#### 3.  Modify the dovecot database config file

In your Dovecot database config file (`dovecot-sql.conf` for me) modify the following:

```
default_pass_scheme = BLF-CRYPT
```

In your Roundcube password plugin config file, modify the following (the rest is the same as my OP):

```
$config['password_dovecotpw_method'] = 'BLF-CRYPT';
$config['password_dovecotpw'] = '/usr/bin/doveadm pw -r 12';
```